# Criar uma Table em tempo de execução. C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, visual-studio-2015, runtime

Olá,
Estou precisando criar uma `table` dentro de um `DB Access` em tempo de execução.

O Banco de Dados já existe, gostaria apenas que, ao clicar em um `button`uma nova `table`fosse criada dentro deste `DB` com  **Nome de Campos** e **Tipo de Dados** todos já pré-definidos, para que todas as novas `tables`sejam criadas com o mesmos **campos**.

```
        OleDbConnection ConSelect = new OleDbConnection();
        ConSelect.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbteste;

        ConSelect.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

        command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable (" +
                        "[Count] INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ," +
                        "[TimeAndDate] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ," +
                        "[SerialNumber] VARCHAR( 14 ) NOT NULL ," +
                        "[Result] BOOL NOT NULL ," +
                        "UNIQUE ([TimeAndDate]))";

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        ConSelect.Close();
```

Este é um modo que eu estava tentando, mas ainda da erro.
 -> Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized. <-

Comment: O que já fez? Qual sua dificuldade específica?

Comment: @bigown Atualmente em minha empresa, cada venda que eu faço, eu faço o `INSERT` de cada produto vendido.. (Dentro de um `DB`, eu tenho uma `TbVendas`, onde faço todos os `INSERTs`).    


Agora estou precisando criar uma nova `Table` para cada venda efetuada.  
(Em um Evento_Click, Criar uma `tbVendas2508` Dentro de um `DB` com os Campos já pré-definidos. (Automatic_Cod, DescProd, PrecoProd... ) e daí fazer o `INSERT`dentro dessa nova `Table`.    

Sobre este problema eu não tenho nada ainda, Trabalho com acesso direto ao banco em OleDB, Access.

Comment: O que isso vai ajudar na sua aplicação? E poste o que você já fez.

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 Ao fazer a saida dos produtos do meu stock, preciso adiciona-los a uma **nota de saida**. portanto, gostaria de criar essa `Tb` para usa-la como sendo a própria **nota de saida**.  Por isso precisa ser em `RunTime`, para que cada vez que necessário criar uma **Nota de saida** eu possa criar uma nova `Table`.

Comment: Porque não dá pra deixar a tabela Notas criada e fazer o insert nela ? o que te obriga a criar uma tabela?

Comment: @Intruso Eu trabalho com Exportação de AutoPeças, moro em Miami e envio para o Brasil. Toda semana eu faço uma **Nota de Saida** com mais ou menos 1200 itens, ou seja cerca de 800`Rows`. Ao final de apenas 1 ano seriam mais de 150`milRows` em uma `TABLE`. Eu acho muita coisa pra fazer uma pesquisa ou uma migração caso um dia seja necessario. Por isso queria separar um `TABLE` pra cada Nota. Posso ate pensar em criar uma `TABLE` para cada mes, pra ficar mais leve, mas ainda assim, precisaria criar em `RunTime`...  
Mas Obrigado pela atenção, consegui o codigo e coloquei como resposta. Abraços!

Comment: Nao faz muito sentido criar uma tabela fisica em tempo de execução em qq situação. Talvez tenha que rever o modelo de banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia! 
Consegui criar a tabela em RunTime, a partir deste código.

```
        OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection();
        Con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbteste;

        Con.Open();
        OleDbCommand Cmm = new OleDbCommand();
        Cmm.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE NOVAFASE (" +
           "[Count] AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
           "[TimeAndDate] VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL," +
           "[SerialNumber] VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL," +
           "[Result] VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL," +
           "UNIQUE([Count]))";


        Cmm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Cmm.Connection = Con;

        Cmm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Inclusão efetuada com Sucesso !");

       Con.Close();
```

Obrigado.